# How do I write another element based on the selections of two interdependent dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[My example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/qsz2x29x/2/)

As shown in the image [image]

The values of the two dropdowns create either an acceptable or unacceptable situation. I'm not versed well enough in JS or JQ to figure out how to figure out how to get this working in an elegant manner. The results span doesn't have to be a span, it's just an indicator where the results need to go.

The trickiest part is that while in this example there are only 4 rows, they are NOT named uniquely because users can add an arbitrary number of rows which are all read into an array in the PHP back end. So, I have to work with this method.

I can kind of imagine a way that could identify the proper cell/span/etc since it sits in the very next TD, but I don't know how to do that, nor how to get dropdown 1 to work in conjunction with dropdown 2 without a lot of redundancy.

I am using jQuery for several things in this form as a whole, so I would presume that could make things a lot easier.

```
<style>
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
span.unacceptable {
    color: firebrick;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.acceptable {
    color: forestgreen;
    font-weight: normal;
}</style>

<script>
var unacceptable = "<span class=\"unacceptable\" id=\"unacceptable\"><input name=\"risks[raw-risk-riskestimate][]\" size=\"10\" value=\"Unacceptable\" type=\"hidden\">Unacceptable<\/span>";
var acceptable = "<span class=\"acceptable\" id=\"acceptable\"><input name=\"risks[raw-risk-riskestimate][]\" size=\"10\" value=\"Acceptable\" type=\"hidden\">Acceptable<\/span>\r\n";
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span id="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span id="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probablity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span id="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span id="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vup31U9.png" />
```

Comment: do you have this Risk matrix in the form of JavaScript array OR JSON object...?

Comment: vijayP: No, but I presume that would be easy to do? The image is there as an example. I'm not sure even how I'd build that. My JS skills aren't strong. A pastebin of the text is here: http://pastebin.com/LMJ9PmNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please take a look at below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/68fwcxeb/3/

I created a JSON object representing risk matrix and utilized it on `select` boxes value change event as follows:

**HTML Code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span class="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span class="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probablity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span class="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Severity:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-severityharm][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Negligible">Negligible</option>
                <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="Catastrophic">Catastrophic</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>Probability:&nbsp;
            <select name="risks[raw-risk-probability][]">
                <option value="badselection" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>
                <option value="Frequent">Frequent</option>
                <option value="Probable">Probable</option>
                <option value="Occasional">Occasional</option>
                <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Inconceivable">Inconceivable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <span class="result">Result</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

One minor change in HTML as instead of `id="result"` I have given `class="result"` because all HTML elements should have unique `id` but multiple elements can have single `class`.

**JQuery code:**

```
var unacceptable = "<span class=\"unacceptable\" id=\"unacceptable\"><input name=\"risks[raw-risk-riskestimate][]\" size=\"10\" value=\"Unacceptable\" type=\"hidden\">Unacceptable<\/span>";
var acceptable = "<span class=\"acceptable\" id=\"acceptable\"><input name=\"risks[raw-risk-riskestimate][]\" size=\"10\" value=\"Acceptable\" type=\"hidden\">Acceptable<\/span>\r\n";

var riskMatrix = {
    "Negligible" : {
        "Frequent": "Unacceptable",
        "Probable": "Acceptable",
        "Occasional": "Acceptable",
        "Remote": "Acceptable",
        "Inconceivable": "Acceptable"
    },
    "Minor" : {
        "Frequent": "Unacceptable",
        "Probable": "Unacceptable",
        "Occasional": "Acceptable",
        "Remote": "Acceptable",
        "Inconceivable": "Acceptable"
    },
    "Serious" : {
        "Frequent": "Unacceptable",
        "Probable": "Unacceptable",
        "Occasional": "Acceptable",
        "Remote": "Acceptable",
        "Inconceivable": "Acceptable"
    },
    "Critical" : {
        "Frequent": "Unacceptable",
        "Probable": "Unacceptable",
        "Occasional": "Unacceptable",
        "Remote": "Acceptable",
        "Inconceivable": "Acceptable"
    },
    "Catastrophic" : {
        "Frequent": "Unacceptable",
        "Probable": "Unacceptable",
        "Occasional": "Unacceptable",
        "Remote": "Unacceptable",
        "Inconceivable": "Acceptable"
    }   
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change", "select[name*=raw-risk-severityharm], select[name*=raw-risk-probability]",function(){
        var currentTrElem = $(this).closest("tr");
        var selectName = $(this).attr("name");
        var currentSeverityharm = null;
        var currentProbability = null;
        var currentResultTD = currentTrElem.find(".result").closest("td");
        var bothSelectChosen = false;

        if(selectName.indexOf("raw-risk-severityharm") > -1)
        {
            currentSeverityharm = $(this).val();
            currentProbability = currentTrElem.find("select[name*=raw-risk-probability]").val();
        }
        else
        {
            currentProbability = $(this).val();
            currentSeverityharm = currentTrElem.find("select[name*=raw-risk-severityharm]").val();
        }


        if(currentSeverityharm != "badselection" && currentProbability != "badselection")
        {
            bothSelectChosen = true;
        }

        if(bothSelectChosen)
        {
            currentResultTD.empty().html('<span class="result">Result</span>');
            var currentResult = riskMatrix[currentSeverityharm][currentProbability];
            if(currentResult == "Unacceptable")
            {
                currentResultTD.append("<br/>"+unacceptable);
            }
            else if(currentResult == "Acceptable")
            {
                 currentResultTD.append("<br/>"+acceptable);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentResultTD.empty().html('<span class="result">Result</span>');
        }
    });

});
```

By using jquery's `$.closest()` and `$.find()` we can find the associated select box and using combination of them we can get the result. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Wow, Amazing, my friend. I was unable to get back yesterday, but this, this is amazing and perfect. And not only that, I understand the whole situation more clearly now. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/6uqd4ge9/3/) that has multiple sets of dropdowns.

---

Here's a solution using a 2D array to store the possible results. Then the values of the two `<select>`s are used as indices to get the result.

HTML:

```
<div>
    Severity:
    <select class="severity">
        <option disabled selected>Choose severity</option>
        <option value="0">Negligible</option>
        <option value="1">Minor</option>
        <option value="2">Serious</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    Probability:
    <select class="probability">
        <option disabled selected>Choose probability</option>
        <option value="0">Frequent</option>
        <option value="1">Probably</option>
        <option value="2">Occasional</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

JS (with jQuery):

```
var table = [
    ['Unacceptable','Unacceptable','Unacceptable'],
    ['Unacceptable','Unacceptable','Acceptable'],
    ['Unacceptable','Acceptable','Acceptable'],
];

$('.severity').on('change', function() {
    var severValue = $(this).val();
    var probValue = $('.probability').val();
    if (severValue && probValue) {
        $('.result').html(table[severValue][probValue]);
    }
});

$('.probability').on('change', function() {
    var severValue = $('.severity').val();
    var probValue = $(this).val();
    if (severValue && probValue) {
        $('.result').html(table[severValue][probValue]);
    }
});
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uqd4ge9/1/).

Comment: I thank you for the reply. However, when there is more than one pair of dropdowns, like in the example, this fails. All the results wind up being updated the same, rather than one at a time. That's the core problem I'm struggling with, I'm not certain how to get the right element per selection.

Comment: @GreyHodge For multiple sets of dropdowns, you need to traverse the DOM and specify elements in relation to each other. Please see the update at the top of my answer.

Comment: I see it,and I'll test it more tomorrow, but at the moment, it looks awesome. By the way, you haven't given a man a fish, I learn best by taking apart things that work, like your code. You have given me a fish, but I saw how you built the pole, so I'll be able to catch my own, or at least try. :)